# i want to align my code in a perfect order of widgets, so that ui look neat and clean

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want a neat and clean UI for my program it's working well but UI is terribly bad. Can anyone help me to fix this?

I am trying to use grid and place, but due to lack of knowledge of python. I am unable to do it.

```
#wap to demonstrate use of check button
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
def pd():
    if (var1.get())==1:
        l1.config(text="You Have Selected Pendrive")
    elif (var1.get())==0:
        l1.config(text="")
def mcard():
    if (var2.get())==1:
        l2.config(text="You Have Selected Memory card")
    elif (var2.get())==0:
        l2.config(text="")
def hdd():
    if (var3.get())==1:
        l3.config(text="You Have Selected HDD")
    elif (var3.get())==0:
        l3.config(text="")
def per():
    print("Successfully compiled")
    msgbox=tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Closing program","Are you sure?",)
    if msgbox=="yes":
        win.destroy()
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Return','You will now return to the application screen')
win=tkinter.Tk()
var1=tkinter.IntVar()
var2=tkinter.IntVar()
var3=tkinter.IntVar()
win.geometry("500x500+0+0")
cb1=tkinter.Checkbutton(text="Pendrive",height=2,width=15,variable=var1,font=5,cursor="dot",bg="grey",anchor="w",command=pd)
cb2=tkinter.Checkbutton(text="Memory Card",height=2,width=15,variable=var2,font=5,cursor="dot",bg="grey",anchor="w",command=mcard)
cb3=tkinter.Checkbutton(text="HDD",height=2,width=15,variable=var3,font=5,cursor="dot",bg="grey",anchor="w",command=hdd)
b1=tkinter.Button(text="Submit",height=2,width=15,command=per)
# from this line problem begins with UI.
l1=tkinter.Label(height=2,width=30)
l2=tkinter.Label(height=2,width=30)
l3=tkinter.Label(height=2,width=30)
cb1.grid(column=0,row=1)
cb2.grid(column=0,row=2)
cb3.grid(column=0,row=3)
l1.place(x=40,y=300)
l2.place(x=40,y=350)
l3.place(x=40,y=400)
b1.place(x=125,y=450)

win.mainloop()
```

Actual results are different than I expected it to be. the widgets are not aligned well(I want them to centered)and there isn't enough padding between them( there should be enough space so that it won't look messy ).

Comment: Widgets have options for changing their alignment, and tkinter has two geometry managers (`pack`, `grid`) that also make alignment easy. Have you read through the documentation and tried using some of the options provided to you?

Comment: documentation: [place()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [pack()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [grid()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want better aligned then rather don't use `width`, `height`, `place()` but `pack()` and `grid()` and its options. If you use wrong option in `pack()`, `grid()` then you will see error message with all available options for `pack` or `grid`. `pack` and `grid` use different options.

More in documentation: [place()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [pack()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [grid()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def pd():
    if var1.get():
        l1.config(text="You Have Selected Pendrive")
    else:
        l1.config(text="")

def mcard():
    if var2.get():
        l2.config(text="You Have Selected Memory card")
    else:
        l2.config(text="")

def hdd():
    if var3.get():
        l3.config(text="You Have Selected HDD")
    else:
        l3.config(text="")

def per():
    print("Successfully compiled")
    msgbox = messagebox.askquestion("Closing program","Are you sure?",)
    if msgbox == "yes":
        win.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Return', 'You will now return to the application screen')


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x500+0+0")

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()
var3 = tk.IntVar()

cb1 = tk.Checkbutton(win, text="Pendrive", variable=var1, font=5, cursor="dot", bg="grey", anchor="w", command=pd)
cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(win, text="Memory Card", variable=var2, font=5, cursor="dot",bg="grey", anchor="w", command=mcard)
cb3 = tk.Checkbutton(win, text="HDD", variable=var3, font=5, cursor="dot", bg="grey", anchor="w", command=hdd)
cb1.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
cb2.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
cb3.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)

l1 = tk.Label(win, background='#bbbbbb')
l2 = tk.Label(win, background='#cccccc')
l3 = tk.Label(win, background='#bbbbbb')
l1.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
l2.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
l3.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)

b1 = tk.Button(win, text="Submit", command=per)
b1.pack(side='bottom', ipadx=10, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)


win.mainloop()
```